# How to sort by two fields (one numeric, one string) at the same time using the built in "sort" program?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sorting

I have a file, lets say "bigfile", with tabular data of the following form,

a1 b2 a3 1
b1 a2 c3 0
... and so on.

I want to use the built-in "sort" program on my Linux machine so sort this file by the fourth field(numeric) and then by the first field at the same time. I went through the man pages a couple of times and all I could come up with was,

```
sort -n -k4,4 -k1,1 bigfile
```

Is there a way to make "sort" do what I want or I have to write my own custom program?

Thank you.

Comment: @Orbit, I believe `-k4` merely *starts* a key at column 4. But the end of the key is not specified and therefore the key goes all the way to the end. So, `-k4 -k1`, is really something more like `-k4 -k5 -k6 -k7 -k1`, and therefore the `-k1` is kinda meaningless. (Yes, it's really counterintuitive, but basically you should always do `-kX,X` for every field

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - Ah, appreciate the response. Thanks kindly!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the manpage:

> POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the
>   field number and C the character
>   position in the field; both are origin
>   1.  If neither -t nor -b is in effect, 
>   characters in a field are counted from
>   the beginning of the preceding
>   whitespace.  OPTS is  one  or  more 
>   single-letter  ordering  options, 
>   which override global ordering options
>   for that key.  If no key is given, use
>   the entire line as the key.

`sort -k4,4n -k1,1 bigfile` ought to do it.

Another option would be `sort -k1,1 bigfile | sort --stable -n -k4,4`  The stable sort means that ties on the 4th field are resolved by the initial position, which is set by the first pass of sort to be first field.