# Unix sort with scientific notation and two columns

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, scientific-notation, exponent

I'm scratching my head about the results of sorting two columns with unix sort.

Here's some dummy data in a file called test:

```
A       2e-12
A       3e-14
A       1e-15
A       1.2e-13
B       1e-13
B       1e-14
C       4e-12
C       3e-12
```

I would like to sort by column 1 first, then column 2, to produce:

```
A       1e-15
A       3e-14
A       1.2e-13
A       2e-12
B       1e-14
B       1e-13
C       3e-12
C       4e-12
```

If I give it just the second column to sort on, it will sort the scientific notation correctly:

```
sort -g -k2 test
A       1e-15
B       1e-14
A       3e-14
B       1e-13
A       1.2e-13
A       2e-12
C       3e-12
C       4e-12
```

[This stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642349/sorting-scientific-number-with-unix-sort) addresses a similar problem, but it seems that my test only breaks down when I ask for two columns to sort on.

[This other example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354145/bash-numeric-sort-gives-different-results-when-columns-are-selected-simultaneous) looks really close to what I want, but when I give separate -k it doesn't alter the behavior for my test set.

These trials:

```
sort -k1,1 -g  test
sort -k1,1 -g -k1,2  test
sort -k1,1 -g -k2,1  test
```

Produce:

```
A       1.2e-13
A       1e-15
A       2e-12
A       3e-14
B       1e-13
B       1e-14
C       3e-12
C       4e-12
```

And these trials:

```
sort -g -k2 -k1  test
sort -g -k2 -k1,1  test
sort -g -k2,2 -k1,1  test
sort -k1,1 -g -k2,2 test
sort -k1,1 -g -k2,2  test
```

Produce:

```
A       1e-15
B       1e-14
A       3e-14
B       1e-13
A       1.2e-13
A       2e-12
C       3e-12
C       4e-12
```

I have tested with LANG=C and LC_ALL=C without luck. I'm running this on Red Hat and the version is GNU coreutils 8.22.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out while writing the stack question, so I thought I'd just go ahead and post the question with my solution.

I was confused about what the -kn,n meant and actually using sort with the --debug flag helped me find the answer.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206033/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-one-numeric-one-string-at-the-same-time-using-the-b) pretty much nails it on the head: always use -kX,X to make sure I'm only considering one field at a time, and then specify g in the numeric field.

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2g test
A       1e-15
A       3e-14
A       1.2e-13
A       2e-12
B       1e-14
B       1e-13
C       3e-12
C       4e-12
```

Yay!